# lightweight webserver communication with c++ application

Tags: c++, asp.net, opencv, webserver

I'm developing an **opencv** console application and I need to communicate with a webserver. I will require to send and receive data.
If there is any lightweight solution with examples I will appreciate your assistance.
The webserver I know is based on ASP.NET with c#.

**Note** that EmguCV is not going to work with me. I prefer to stick with the standard c++ environment.

Comment: Please note that asking for recommendations for libraries and tools is off-topic hear. Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs. Something from there might work for you.

Comment: Thank you R Sahu, I'm asking for any type of guidance not strictly libraries. Will look into your link as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is better to let you know what I've done.
Basically, I just created my c++ application in a CLR project so I can call .Net classes and use Forms as well.

Comment: Appreciate that you came back after all this time just to say you've solved it.